# Regex for matching a pokerhand (Java)

Tags: java, regex

Regex rookie here.

I need a regex that matches a specific poker hand (Full House - a poker hand containing three cards of one rank and two cards of another rank) It should recognize it as a full house with the cards in any arbitrary order and with all card ranks (23456789TJQKA) and suits (SHDC)

I'm not even sure regex is the right tool for this, so please tell me if you think I should do something else :)

an example string could look like

> "KD KC AH AC AD"
>
> (King of Diamonds, King of Clubs, Ace of Hearts, Ace of Clubs, Ace of
>   Diamonds)

I've come up with this ugly regex

```
(?=.*(([2-9TJQKA])[SHDC]).*\2[SHDC].*\2[SHDC])(?=.*(?!\2)(([2-9TJQKA])[SHDC]).*\4[SHDC].*\4[SHDC]).*
```

but it does not seem to do the job.

Comment: What string do you get? And what do you need to get?

Comment: I wouldn't do it with a regex, you can write a simple method that checks if the hand holds only two different ranks and if one of the ranks shows exactly three times. This should be an easy method to write and maintain and as a bonus you'll get better performance because you're not using regex.

Comment: Matching entire string with with matches() method from String class, and according to regexr.com I don't match anything

Comment: Nah you are probably right :) It's just whenever I have to do some advanced string matching I always jump to the conclusion that regex is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should match 'full houses': (edit: and is really just your original regex fixed up to ignore the suit)

```
(?=.*([2-9TJQKA])[SHDC].*\1[SHDC].*\1[SHDC])(?=.*((?!\1)[2-9TJQKA])[SHDC].*\2[SHDC])
```

It looks for the "3" sequence with the first lookahead. the second lookahead, which  is looking for the "2" sequence, includes a negative lookahead within it to prevent duplicate matching. The regex is composed entirely of two lookaheads, which prevent the issues that would arise if we actually matched (and moved the pointer ahead) any characters - both of these subpatterns are free to match anywhere in the string.

[online demo here](https://regex101.com/r/UWlmbb/1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a regex, you could use a guava Multimap and check if you have only two different ranks, then check if one of those ranks has 3 suits.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        String s = "KD KC AH AC AD";
        Splitter splitter = Splitter.on(' ');
        System.out.println(checkFullHouse(splitter.split(s)));
    }

    private static boolean checkFullHouse(Iterable<String> in) {
        Multimap<String, Object> m = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        Splitter splitter = Splitter.fixedLength(1);
        in.forEach(s -> {
            List<String> l = Lists.newArrayList(splitter.split(s));
            m.put(l.get(0), l.get(1));
        });
        return m.keySet().size() == 2 && (int) m.keySet().stream().filter(v -> m.get(v).size() == 3).count() == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Multimap before, but this looks way more simple. Gonna look into it :)

Comment: Do not use the keyword `assert` to verify inputs! Also, if you use Guava, favor the `Splitter` class instead of the method `String::split` (because `split` uses regexes... If you want to avoid them, avoid them ;)

Comment: Changed it @OlivierGrégoire